# ostrio:files with Dropbox on Meteor

Tags: meteor, file-upload, dropbox, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to setup ostrio:files to work with dropbox. Can someone please explain me how to do it?
I've registered on dropbox and generated token using ostrio:files manual but I don't know how to upload files to dropbox.
After upload, when I check local Images db there are all images information but I don't know how to send it to Dropbox.

After file select, it says “upload successful” but there are no files uploaded on Dropbox.

dropbox.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { FilesCollection } from 'meteor/ostrio:files';

var Dropbox,
  Request,
  bound,
  client,
  fs,
  Images = {};

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Dropbox = require("dropbox").Dropbox;
  const fetch = require("node-fetch");
  bound = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (callback) {
    return callback();
  });
  client = new Dropbox({
    accessToken: "mytoken", // Use your token here
    fetch: fetch,
  });
}

Request = require("request");
fs = require("fs");

Images.files = new FilesCollection({
  debug: false, // Change to `true` for debugging
  storagePath: "assets/app/uploads/uploadedFiles",
  collectionName: "uploadedFiles",
  allowClientCode: false,
  onAfterUpload: function (fileRef) {
    // In onAfterUpload callback we will move file to DropBox
    try {
      var self = this;
      var makeUrl = function (path, fileRef, version) {
        client
          .sharingCreateSharedLink({ path: path, short_url: false })
          .then(function (response) {
            bound(function () {
              const url = response.url.replace("dl=0", "raw=1");
              var upd = {
                $set: {},
              };
              upd["$set"]["versions." + version + ".meta.pipeFrom"] = url;
              upd["$set"]["versions." + version + ".meta.pipePath"] = path;
              self.collection.update(
                {
                  _id: fileRef._id,
                },
                upd,
                function (error) {
                  if (error) {
                    return console.error(error);
                  }
                  // Unlink original files from FS after successful upload to DropBox
                  self.unlink(self.collection.findOne(fileRef._id), version);
                }
              );
            });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };

      var writeToDB = function (fileRef, version, data) {
        // DropBox already uses random URLs
        // No need to use random file names
        client
          .filesUpload({
            path: "/" + fileRef._id + "-" + version + "." + fileRef.extension,
            contents: data,
            autorename: false,
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            bound(function () {
              // The file was successfully uploaded, generating a downloadable link
              makeUrl(response.path_display, fileRef, version);
            });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            bound(function () {
              console.error(error);
            });
          });
      };

      var readFile = function (fileRef, vRef, version) {
        fs.readFile(vRef.path, function (error, data) {
          bound(function () {
            if (error) {
              return console.error(error);
            }
            writeToDB(fileRef, version, data);
          });
        });
      };

      var sendToStorage = function (fileRef) {
        _.each(fileRef.versions, function (vRef, version) {
          readFile(fileRef, vRef, version);
        });
      };

      sendToStorage(fileRef);
    } catch (error) {
      // There was an error while uploading the file to Dropbox, displaying the concerned file
      console.log(
        "The following error occurred while removing " + fileRef.path
      );
      // Removing the file from the file system
      fs.unlink(fileRef.path, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
      // Removing the file from the collection
      Images.files.remove(
        {
          _id: fileRef._id,
        },
        function (error) {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  },
  onBeforeRemove: function (cursor) {
    return false;
  },
  interceptDownload: function (http, fileRef, version) {
    // Files are stored in Dropbox, intercepting the download to serve the file from Dropbox
    var path, ref, ref1, ref2;
    path =
      (ref = fileRef.versions) != null
        ? (ref1 = ref[version]) != null
          ? (ref2 = ref1.meta) != null
            ? ref2.pipeFrom
            : void 0
          : void 0
        : void 0;
    if (path) {
      // If file is moved to DropBox
      // We will pipe request to DropBox
      // So, original link will stay always secure
      Request({
        url: path,
        headers: _.pick(
          http.request.headers,
          "range",
          "accept-language",
          "accept",
          "cache-control",
          "pragma",
          "connection",
          "upgrade-insecure-requests",
          "user-agent"
        ),
      })
        .on("response", function (response) {
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            response.headers = _.pick(
              response.headers,
              "accept-ranges",
              "cache-control",
              "connection",
              "content-disposition",
              "content-length",
              "content-type",
              "date",
              "etag"
            );
            response.headers["Cache-control"] =
              "only-if-cached, public, max-age=2592000";
          }
        })
        .pipe(http.response);
      return true;
    } else {
      // While file is not yet uploaded to DropBox
      // We will serve file from FS
      return false;
    }
  },
});

// if (Meteor.isServer) {
//   // Intercept File's collection remove method to remove file from DropBox

//   var _origRemove = Images.files.remove; // Catching the original remove method to call it after
//   Images.files.remove = function (search) {
//     var cursor = this.collection.find(search);
//     cursor.forEach(function (fileRef) {
//       _.each(fileRef.versions, function (vRef) {
//         var ref;
//         if (
//           vRef != null
//             ? (ref = vRef.meta) != null
//               ? ref.pipePath
//               : void 0
//             : void 0
//         ) {
//           client
//             .filesDeleteV2({ path: vRef.meta.pipePath })
//             .catch(function (error) {
//               bound(function () {
//                 console.error(error);
//               });
//             });
//         }
//       });
//     });
//     // Call original method
//     _origRemove.call(this, search);
//   };
// }

export default Images; // import in other files
```

uploadForm.js

```
import { Template }    from 'meteor/templating';

import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import Images from '/lib/dropbox.js';

Template.uploadForm.onCreated(function () {

  this.currentUpload = new ReactiveVar(false);

});

Template.uploadForm.helpers({

  currentUpload() {

    return Template.instance().currentUpload.get();

  }

});

Template.uploadForm.events({

  'change #fileInput'(e, template) {

      console.log("file opened");

    if (e.currentTarget.files && e.currentTarget.files[0]) {

      // We upload only one file, in case

      // multiple files were selected

      const upload = Images.files.insert({

        file: e.currentTarget.files[0],

        streams: 'dynamic',

        chunkSize: 'dynamic'

      }, false);

      upload.on('start', function () {

        template.currentUpload.set(this);

        console.log("start upload");

      });

      upload.on('end', function (error, fileObj) {

        if (error) {

          alert(`Error during upload: ${error}`);

        } else {

          alert(`File "${fileObj.name}" successfully uploaded`);

        }

        template.currentUpload.set(false);

      });

      upload.start();

    }

  }

});
```

uploadForm.html

```html
<template name="uploadForm">
    {{#with currentUpload}}
      Uploading <b>{{file.name}}</b>:
      <span id="progress">{{progress.get}}%</span>
    {{else}}
      <input id="fileInput" type="file" />
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

when i try to upload I get this in server console

```
[FilesCollection] [File Start Method] img.png - ms75Ah76svrFEGh2f
[FilesCollection] [Upload] [DDP Start Method] Got #-1/1 chunks, dst: img.png
[FilesCollection] [Upload] [DDP] Got #1/1 chunks, dst: img.png
[FilesCollection] [Upload] [DDP] Got #-1/1 chunks, dst: img.png     
[FilesCollection] [Upload] [finish(ing)Upload] -> tmp\ms75Ah76svrFEGh2f.png
[FilesCollection] [Upload] [finish(ed)Upload] -> tmp\ms75Ah76svrFEGh2f.png 
The following error occurred while removing tmp\ms75Ah76svrFEGh2f.png      
[FilesCollection] [remove({"_id":"ms75Ah76svrFEGh2f"})]
[FilesCollection] [unlink(ms75Ah76svrFEGh2f, undefined)]
[FilesCollection] [_preCollectionCursor.observe] [changed]: ms75Ah76svrFEGh2f
[FilesCollection] [_preCollectionCursor.observe] [removed]: ms75Ah76svrFEGh2f
```

Comment: `but I don't know how to send it to Dropbox` there is lots of code in `onAfterUpload`  that handles sending data to Dropbox. You need to be more specific in what exactly is not working. Pasting as much code as possible won't help. Please narrow down to what exactly is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it.

Comment: The upload message is only related to the file being uploaded to *your* server. The dropbox upload happens in the `afterUpload` method. You need to check the server console for messages and errors etc.

Comment: thanks, I've added server console messages in post above.

Comment: You need to add more console.log in the part where actually the dopbox upload happens, the current output is very general.